# spring boot load data from list

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to put data from user list to frontend in spring but i have no idea how to do it.
For example with static file something.json it works but how can i create it from list.
This is my frontend

```
<tr th:each="user: ${users}">
    <td th:text="${user.id}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.firstName}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.lastName}"></td>
</tr>
```

and this is my spring boot main file

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Engine company = new Engine();
        User user;
        Travel travel;
        User employee;
        user = company.createUser("gfdgfd","gfdgdf",49484894,"gfdgfdg@fdgfd.com",918191,"Bratislava","Ulica",456);
        employee = company.createUser("Andrej","g",49489dgdf4,"gfdgfdg@fdgfd.com",918191,"Bratislava","Ulica",456);
        company.listUsers();
        company.listUser(user.getID());
        company.editUser(user.getID(),"Jg","g"fgfd,494848fdgfd",94,"gfdgfdg@fdgfd.com",918191,"Bratislava","Ulica",456);
        travel = company.lifeIT(employee, LocalDate.of(2020,1,1),LocalDate.of(2021,1,1),5000,100,user,false,EnumActivity.valueOf("WORK"));
        user.setContracts(travel.getID());
        company.listInsurances();
        company.listInsurance(employee.getID());
        company.editlifeIT(travel.getID(),employee, LocalDate.of(2020,1,1),LocalDate.of(2022,1,1),5000,1000,user,false,EnumActivity.valueOf("SPORT"));


        SpringApplication.run(MvcListApplication.class, args);
        log.info("Open in browser: http://localhost:8080");
    }
}
```

I am creating one employee and one user to have some data. So how can I print that user (let's say there will be more users) to frontend? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U need a @Controller class wich who should have the responsibility to take your list to your html.

That class, should have a method for this:

```
@GetMapping("/all")
public String showAll(Model model) {
 model.addAttribute("books", bookService.findAll());
 return "books/allBooks";
}
```

Where "GetMapping" is ur url, Model is a object that binds the objects to ur html, and return is a path of ur html file.

U can follow tutorial bellow for more informations:
https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list

Comment: Thanks its my first day with spring boot because of school homework and i totally miss is same MVC concept as everything else. Thank you very much.